# DataGridView event when a cell value changes automatically

Tags: c#, .net, events, data-binding, datagridview

There's a `DataGridView`, whose `DataSource` is `IEnumerable<SomeClass>`.

**The grid is read-only for the user.** Its contents does change to reflect certain user actions, but the user cannot edit cells directly.

`SomeClass`, to an instance of which each row is bound, implements [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).
Because of this, when a property of an instance changes, DataGridView automatically picks that up and changes corresponding value in its cell. **I want to handle that event.**

`DataBindingComplete` is no good because only happens on list reset and does not happen on an item change.
`CellValidated` is no good because it happens all the time when I simply navigate between cells.

I can add my own handlers to each instance's `INotifyPropertyChanged` event. That will work. But because `DataGridView` is already doing it, I would like to ask it instead of duplicating number of active event listeners.

**How can that be done?**

Comment: Is this a web app or windows app?

Comment: @David.Chu.ca This is a windows app.